# How to set up Shibboleth authentication for a MU site

Tags: authentication

So far I haven't found an easy set up plugin that works.

["shibboleth"](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/shibboleth/) is over 2 years out of date.

["HTTP authentication"](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/http-authentication/) might work, but I haven't figured out how to set it up yet.

I have an IDP set up that work. I have Drupal and Moodle both using it. So I just need to be able to get Wordpress working.